# Twitter : Your account may not be allowed to perform this action. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: twitter

I have this error on twitter :
[Twitter Error Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5i6t.jpg)
When I :

- try to send a Tweet
- try to edit my profil

Additionnaly I can access to "your twitter data" in settings and can't unfollow people.

My account seems limited.

Comment: I use Firefox 42.0 and I seems to occured only with Firefox.
[link](https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/943968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your account may not be allowed to perform this action. Please refresh the page and try again.

Firefox about:config **network.http.sendRefererHeader** must be set to its default value of "**2**".

Comment: Since my question I updated firefox a few time and I'm now using FF 59.0. Today I have no problem with my twitter account **network.http.sendRefererHeader** is set to **2**. You're solution certainly fix the problem. I will accept this answer as the solution but I can't checked it works.